# Passing variable to promoted QWidget

Tags: qt, qwidget

I have two classes:

-MainWindow

-MyWidget which is promoted in MainWindow.ui using QT Creator's design tab.
Both of the class .ui's are designed in design tab.

I try to pass variables to MyWidget from MainWindow without any success. Compiler doesn't give any errors, but variables are not passing. Is there any way to do this? MyWidget works well as long as I don't import MainWindow to it or import MyWidget to MainWindow. After import I can't control MyWidget's content by code. Any suggestions?

EDIT: Made a small example and added code to pastebin, so this post won't get bloated.

[MainWindow.h](http://pastebin.com/pt9Rd1tE)

[MainWindow.cpp](http://pastebin.com/atHv6JaS)

another links are in comments

Comment: Your question is not clear. You cannot achieve some visibility in Designer? That is quite unclear. Should that be a code problem we would answer. I personally don't use Designer. Not much can be achieved with it but solving real problems is coding.

Comment: MyWidget.h http://pastebin.com/Ldq9HaEj
MyWidget.cpp http://pastebin.com/9RNvWiZ2
MainWindow.ui http://pastebin.com/TV803AXP
MyWidget.ui http://pastebin.com/TV803AXP

Comment: In this example I'm trying to pass text to another class and set it as Label's text. I think that the problem is in promotion. You can see the lines in bottom of .ui files.

Comment: I see the line `connect(this, SIGNAL(text(QString, QString)),&mw, SLOT(addText(QString,QString)));` but you need to give some value to the `mw` variable. It isn't initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class `MainWindow` does not need to a `MyWidget` attribute. `MyWidget` object is actually created by `Ui::MainWindow` object.

So, to access your `MyWidget` object (the one displayed on screen as part of `MainWindow` widget), use `ui->widget` (as widget is the name you gave the object in Qt Designer `<widget class="MyWidget" name="widget" native="true"/>`), instead of `mw`.

Modifying `mw` makes no sense because this instance of `MyWidget` is not used for GUI display.

You then have to change:

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(text(QString, QString)),&mw, SLOT(addText(QString,QString)));
```

into:

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(text(QString, QString)),ui->widget, SLOT(addText(QString,QString)));
```

Note: If `MyWidget` class needs parameters to be passed upon construction, you can remove the `widget`instanciation from your .ui file and create it locally using `mw` attribute of the `MainWindow` class as you did. But, then, to have this instance be shown on screen, you must add it to the layout of your `MainWindow`, like this (for example): `ui->horizontalLayout->addWidget( &mw );`

Comment: Awesome, it is working! Thank you very much for detailed answer!